# Multiple option short-answer exam question

Tags: exam

I'm using Philip Hirschhorn's `exam` document class for an exam paper, and I'd like to include a question in which students can choose two options from a range of questions. My approach is as shown below:

```
\titledquestion{Student-choice question}
Answer \underline{TWO} of the following questions:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Explain whether you think \LaTeX{} is better than Word
\item Explain whether you think vi is better than Emacs
\item Explain whether you think OS X is better than Windows
\item Explain whether you think Android is better than iOS
\end{enumerate}
\begin{parts}
\part[6] First choice
\fillwithlines[6cm]
\part[6] Second choice
\fillwithlines[6cm]
\end{parts}
```

Is there a more standardised and/or better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
    \question Answer \underline{TWO} of the following questions:
    \begin{parts}
      \part[6] Explain whether you think \LaTeX{} is better than Word.
      \part[6] Explain whether you think vi is better than Emacs
      \part[6] Explain whether you think OS X is better than Windows
      \part[6] Explain whether you think Android is better than iOS
    \end{parts}
    First choice:
    \fillwithlines{6cm}
    Second choice:
    \fillwithlines{6cm}
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or this:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
    \uplevel{Answer \underline{TWO} of the following questions:}
      \question[6] Explain whether you think \LaTeX{} is better than Word.
      \question[6] Explain whether you think vi is better than Emacs
      \question[6] Explain whether you think OS X is better than Windows
      \question[6] Explain whether you think Android is better than iOS

    First choice:
    \fillwithlines{6cm}
    Second choice:
    \fillwithlines{6cm}
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

will be my choices.

Comment: I'll just add for posterity that I used the first option (using `part`s), but I wrapped the `parts` environment with `\noaddpoints` and `\addpoints` to avoid screwing up my point count.